# Is it possible to extend a h2 box in CSS depending on the text within it?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a header box appearing on a page.

I am using `h2` and configured this to show a border etc.

My issue is that the longest text requires a **box of 400px wide**, whereas the shortest is probably around **100px** leaving a large gap.

Is there any way to control the width of the `h2` over and above setting a fixed width in **css**?

Comment: please show your code ?

Comment: I ought to add that currently I am simply using <h2 style="width: 500px;">{$data['record']['category_name']}</h2>  -  the category name is pulled in automatically from a database - as a result it can be long or short depending upon the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
div{
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    background-color: #777;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pQc3d/42/)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can apply `float: left` to H2