# Pure Css Popup and Container margin

Tags: html, css

I created a pure css popup by combining http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/css-tooltip and http://cssarrowplease.com/ together. When you hover over "John Smith", a popup appear. You can see this code at http://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/MwEgQX.

However, I am having problems. I wanted to keep everything at the right of the page and yet stay in the container. I tried to edit it by removing the `"overflow: hidden; height: auto;"` from .quotename. When removed, the popup works and yet, it's out of bounds. When the code is added, the code is in bound but the popup isn't working because it overflows its boundaries. How do I fix it?

HTML

```
<div class="testimonials">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="quotename">
                <a href="#" class="tooltip">
                <span><h3>Mini profile</h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consect etur adipiscing elit.</span>
                <h2>John Smith</h2></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.testimonials { background-color: #e7d6e9; padding: 30px 0;}
.container { width: 90%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; background-color: #e9e9e9;}
.quotename {  margin: 20px 0; position: relative; /*overflow: hidden; height: auto;*/}
a.tooltip {outline:none;}
a.tooltip h2 { text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 2px solid #00acb6; font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; font-weight: 700; font-size: 20px; color: #00acb6; float: right; width: auto; margin: 0;}
a.tooltip strong {line-height:30px;}
a.tooltip:hover {text-decoration:none;} 
a.tooltip span {
    display:none; 
    padding:14px 20px;
    margin-top:-120px; 
    margin-right: -8px;
    width:150px; 
    line-height:16px;
    background: #e9e9e9;
    height: 70px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
a.tooltip span h3 { margin:0;}
a.tooltip span:after, a.tooltip span:before {
    top: 100%;
    left: 75%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}
a.tooltip span:after {
    border-color: rgba(0, 172, 182, 0);
    border-top-color: #e9e9e9;
    border-width: 10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
a.tooltip span:before {
    border-color: rgba(0, 172, 182, 0);
    border-top-color: #00acb6;
    border-width: 14px;
    margin-left: -14px;
}
a.tooltip:hover span{
    display:inline; position:relative; color:#111;
    border: 3px solid #00acb6; background: #e9e9e9; border-radius: 6px;}
a.tooltip span
{
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 3px solid #00acb6;
}
```

This is the code in which the popup works but everything is out of bound. You can also see the second code in which everything is in bound but the popup isn't working at http://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/BNwaGq. Please make sure that there's no Javascript involved.

I also did some eliminating methods and found out that the floats in a.tooltip span and a.tooltip h2 can also affect the code too since using the floats can take the content out of bounds or something like that.

Update-
I think the problem lies in the a.tooltip h2. If I remove the float:right from the class, everything works except for the bottom border which is 100% wide. I use that code from [Is it possible to extend a h2 box in CSS depending on the text within it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699750/is-it-possible-to-extend-a-h2-box-in-css-depending-on-the-text-within-it) to fix that problem since I want space between the underline and the text but apparently, that code is affecting the whole thing. The new code is at http://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/RPLwmy

Answer (score 0):

Remove margin-top from this class `a.tooltip span{}`, [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xfhj6scc/2/)

Comment: Sorry, It didn't work. Check out the new code I mentioned in the update I added to the question: http://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/RPLwmy

Comment: Can you please tell exactly where the tool tip need to show when hover over h2 element.

Comment: the tool tip box popup should be over the text. But it doesn't need to be fixed since that's where I wanted it to be. What I am concerned about is the underline/border-bottom, and the content staying in its own place with margin at top and bottom of the content (John Smith").